# get the revision number of a specific file in perforce from a python script

Tags: python, perforce, maya

I'm trying to write a python script which will run when Maya loads. The script should check a number stored in the file somewhere, possibly just a names object, and compare it to the latest revision of the file in perforce.

if the number stored in maya is not the latest revision, it should show a warning. is this possible?

Comment: It's possible - but how it's done depends on language and the api your using. Can you edit the question to indicate mel vs python and if you're using the p4Python API, a commandline p4 client, or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure what I will be using, only that it will be python and link into perforce

Answer (score 0):

To ask if the contents of your file on your workstation matches the content of the current head revision of the file on the server, you can do something like 'p4 diff -f //depot/path/to/file#head'.